# What is the best way to access sharepoint lists?

Tags: 2010, list, linq

In the past I tried with linq using spmetal, but after the project was almost finished I realized of some limitations, this tool does not generate fields for creation date, modified date, also it doesnt work for lookup columns.  So at the end I ended with a combination of LINQ to Sharepoint and also CAML.

From the development point of view which is the best way? Specially if I need to access by code special columns like images, lookup fields, metadata service fields, users, creation date, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

linq to sharepoint -in my opinion- is great, but yes it does have some limitations. From a development point of view I try to use it as much as possible knowing it's fairly new and will get even better. This article may help you decide whether to use it in your situation. 
http://www.sharepointblues.com/2010/09/08/linq-to-sharepoint-performance-pitfalls/

good luck.